# How to split a dataframe in a list based on another list that contains observations indices?

Tags: r

Good afternoon!

I have a list of `L1` of 3 dataframes :

```
obersvations    clusters
<dbl>   <dbl>
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   1
7   1
8   1
9   1
10  1
   
A tibble: 60 × 2 obersvations   clusters
<dbl>   <dbl>
51  2
52  2
53  2
54  2
55  2
56  2
57  2
59  2
60  2
A tibble: 37 × 2 obersvations   clusters
<dbl>   <dbl>
101 3
102 3
103 3
104 3
105 3
106 3
```

From that list , i'm wanting to create a `list` L2 where each element represent a cluster within `iris` observations :

```
data=iris[,-5]
L2=list(data[1:10,],data[51:60,],data[101:106,])
```

In fact , `L1`could change from one iteration to another.

Thank you for help in advance !

Comment: I tried with dplyr join without success

Comment: please post a preview of the expected output

Comment: L2 is the expected output !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to iterate over `L1` and select corresponding rows from `data`.

```
L3 <- lapply(L1, function(x) data[x$obersvations, ])
```

Comment: Yes , this is more elegant than my solution. Thank you a lot sir !

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, we can do

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
L3 <- map(L1, ~ data %>% 
                     slice(.x$obersvations))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had found a solution :

```
v=sapply(1:length(L1),function(i) as.vector(L1[[i]]["obersvations"]))         
lapply(1:length(L1),function(i) iris[v[[i]],-5] )
```